# How to set up terraform behind proxy?

Tags: proxy, terraform

I am trying to run terraform behind a proxy on Windows. I have already set my proxy on CMD by doing: set HTTP_PROXY and set HTTPS_PROXY.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws:
could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery
document: Get "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json":
proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

There are no problem in my infrastructure as I have already tried it on another computer with no proxy and it works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you ping the registry.terraform.io or access the URL via curl or just from a browser? This could be a URL that needs unblocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using terraform proxy with password, by setting environment variables like the following:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
```

set **HTTPS_PROXY** to http url **not** https

Comment: That is a really bad idea.  To have username and password in unencrypted form on any device as environment variables is how hacks happen.  Don't do it.  Your proxy should offer a port that allows for Kerberos authentication so you could use that with a Windows or Mac laptop.  For Linux (i.e. WSL), Kerberos auth can be added as shown here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1033953/how-to-use-windows-kerberos-ticket-in-wsl-and-or-docker

Comment: I'd assume he's everyone is running this from their development machines.  I'm having trouble getting TF to respect the proxy on my mac, even using lowercase variants of the env name.  Is there some other place where the proxy should be set?